Font setting not working on JFace TableViewer in Eclipse 4.23 but working on eclipse photon
I am trying to changing font in my TableViewer in eclipse 4.23 but it's not applying but same changes working in eclipse photon.
I am trying to changing font in my TableViewer in eclipse 4.23 Preferences -> General -> Appearance -> Colors And Fonts -> Basic -> Text Font
I want to apply my changes in TableViewer

Is this a table in a plug-in added to Eclipse? The "View and Editor folders" > "Tree and table font for views" setting is used for view fonts. You can use the CSS Spy to see what CSS is being applied to your table.

What greg-449 says: see here and here. By the way, Eclipse 4.23 is two years and 8 releases behind. Please upgrade.
